# -webkit-transform: rotate - hides elements on top

Tags: css, webkit, css-transforms

I'm using `-webkit-transform: rotate(40 deg)` and it seems that the rotated element is hiding parts of elements which are on top ( **not children** ) of the rotated one.

I created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vzw8T/) with the code, since it will be easier to demonstrate.

Probably this is because the rotated element hides parts of other elements, but I don't want this effect. How can I fix that?

I used `z-index` but it doesn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a 3D transform. You have 'rotateY' in the fiddle not 'rotate'.
So you're moving part of the plane in front of the buttons.
Check for yourself by changing code for the second button to

```
$("div.buttonB").click( function() {
    $("div.background").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(-190deg)')
});
```

​This way after clicking buttonB, buttonB will be clickable but buttonA won't. 
Now change -190deg to 190deg and you'll see that it works other way around.

If you want to wrap your head around 3D transformations check out this site.

http://thewebrocks.com/demos/3D-css-tester/

Watch the video and play with the controls. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, but why when I rotate an element 90 degrees ( if the element is flat this means to show it's back ) then I have this Box - beginning from the center of the rotated element till the end of it, that is on top of every other tag ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you rotate a flat surface 90 degrees you should get a "rectangle" which in this case width equals 0. In that case both buttons are clickable.

Comment: Well I have an update for this. I think it is a bug in Chrome for MAC OS X ... I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4Tec/) . I'm gonna write an issue