# Mouseover doesn't register on rotated div

Tags: html, css

I'm flipping a div using css3 transform rotateY. There's a button on the back of the div. It works fine most of the time but doesn't register a mouseover few times right after the div is completely rotated.

HTML 
    Hover Count:

```
<flip-tile heading="Free Test" message="Take FREE TEST to earn embibium crystals!" status="'locked'" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <div class="flip-holder locked" ng-class="status">
      <div class="front">
        <h3 class="title ng-binding">
          Free Test
        </h3>
        <img alt="Flip Button" class="flip-button" src="/assets/ts_metro_theme/flip-btn.png"><i class="lock-button fa fa-lock"></i><!-- ngIf: stats.rating=='champ' --><span class="count">2 of 3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back ng-scope" ng-if="status=='locked'">
      <div class="buy-holder">
        <span class="ng-binding">Click to unlock all JEE Main tests for</span><!-- ngIf: price --><button ng-if="price" class="ng-scope ng-binding"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>999</button><!-- end ngIf: price -->
      </div>
      <img alt="flip-btn" class="flip-button" src="/assets/ts_metro_theme/flip-btn.png">
    </div>
    </div>
  </flip-tile>
```

css

```
flip-tile {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open sans', 'Quicksand', Helvetica;
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px; }

flip-tile .flip-holder,
flip-tile .front,
flip-tile .back {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit; }

flip-tile span.count {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none; }

flip-tile h3.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px; }

flip-tile .back p {
  margin: 10px; }

flip-tile .lock-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  display: none; }

flip-tile .lock-button {
  display: none; }

flip-tile .locked .lock-button {
  display: inline-block; }

flip-tile .flip-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 23px;
  display: inline-block; }

flip-tile .imp-chapter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  color: #fbfdaa; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats {
  margin: 27px 10px; }

flip-tile .buy-holder {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 14px; }

flip-tile .buy-holder span {
  display: block; }

flip-tile .buy-holder button {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .buy-holder button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444; }

flip-tile .front .champ-badge {
  width: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 6px; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats img {
  width: 17px; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats > div {
  margin: 4px 0; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats span {
  width: 106px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right; }

flip-tile .flip-holder .front,
flip-tile .flip-holder .back {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .locked .front,
flip-tile .locked .back {
  background-color: #888;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .started .front,
flip-tile .started .back,
flip-tile .fresh .front,
flip-tile .fresh .back {
  background-color: #29b8eb;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .good .front,
flip-tile .good .back {
  background-color: #55a417;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .average .front,
flip-tile .average .back {
  background-color: #f29c21;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .bad .front,
flip-tile .bad .back {
  background-color: #f22133;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .fa-repeat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 156px;
  left: 10px; }

flip-tile .flip-holder {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  -moz-perspective: 100px;
  -ms-perspective: 100px;
  -o-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit; }

flip-tile:hover .flip-holder {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg); }

flip-tile .flip-holder {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative; }

flip-tile .front,
flip-tile .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; }

flip-tile .front {
  z-index: 2; }

flip-tile .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg); }
```

js

```
var i=0;
$('flip-tile .back button').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('span.count').html(++i);
});
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/HKWFL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by the parent container which appears to be overlayed over the top of the button on the rotated back element. I had a mess around with your JS Fiddle then stripped it back to its bare essentials ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/HKWFL/5/)) and the issue still occurred. I did a google search for "*obscured elements when 3d transforming*" and found a couple of posts which didn't really help; specifically [this page on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169760/webkit-transform-rotate-hides-elements-on-top) which led me to this page:

http://thewebrocks.com/demos/3D-css-tester/

On this page, the elements that make up the rotating image remain clickable throughout so I got the source and tinkered with that so it did the same thing yours did originally and it worked but wouldn't stay hovered. So I wrapped everything in a parent element to preserve the hover area and then the problem started again!

This made me think that the parent was obscuring the content at the back after the rotation was complete, so I used an additional property of `translateZ(10px)` to offset it away from the parent and it now works perfectly.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/AB8GG/1/

Apologies for the mark-up change, it needed to be broken down to ensure nothing else was interfering with it. You can easily apply the CSS to your original solution though.

Comment: You rock! was struggling with this for ages